# Wso2 APIM 3.0.0 : /Publisher not showing login page

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have followed the steps given here https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM300/Installation+Guide for WSO2 APIM 3.0.0. I have started the gateway. but when i try to get on /pulisher i get an error in browser developer console. please advise whats wrong. thanks.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
index.js:34 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (index.js:34)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (index.js:34)
```

https://xxxxxxxxxx:9292/publisher
[image]

Comment: Have you started WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 as instructed in the docs? Are  you running all the servers in your machine/server?

Comment: yes. i did. i have started,WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 , Apache ActiveMQ 5.14.0, WSO2 APIM Data Analytics Server 3.0.0 M6, API Manager 3.0.0 M6, and API Manager Gateway 3.0.0 M6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for my issue, there is a file index.js inside publisher webapp. this file has reference to localhost (w.default.get("https://localhost:9292/login/login/publisher"), replaced localhost with my hostname and it worked !!

```
/wso2apim-3.0.0-m6/deployment/webapps/publisher/public/dist/index.js
```

Comment: This is fixed in M7.